# Выражение "подвести под монастырь"

Tags: фразеология

"Подвести под монастырь" — говоря современным языком, "подставить". А какое происхождение у этого выражения, что оно означало раньше?

Answer (score 4):

Версий происхождения этого фразеологизма немало. Например, фразеологизм  возник потому, что в монастырь часто уходили люди с серьезными неприятности в жизни.  Или  потому, что русские воины подводили врагов под стены монастырей, превращавшихся на время войны в крепости . Возможно также, что это выражение символизирует тяжелую жизнь женщин в царской России. Ведь если муж наносил жене побои, то родственники  в таких случаях отправлялись искать защиты у патриарха и властей, и если ее находили — то жена «подводила мужа под монастырь», т.е. отправляла его «на смирение» на полгода или год. Мне нравится первая версия, простая, ясная.

Comment: Всё бы хорошо, но предлог "под" объясняет только одна версия, про врагов и монастырские стены. Зато в ней сомнительна историчность.(((

Answer (score 2):

Это не ответ, просто общее обсуждение.
Есть версия, что исходным было выражение "подвести **слепого** под монастырь", в таком виде оно и сейчас еще используется.

А это несколько меняет смысл.

Почему именно слепого?
Ну например потому, что отправление естественных надобностей под стенами монастыря считалось в высшей степени святотатством. Но слепой-то не разбирает, что там за стена... 
Как ни странно, именно у этой, весьма, казалось бы, экзотической версии, я не вижу формальных недостатков. Главное, что ничего за уши притягивать не надо. Более того, возможно, что изначально выражение было еще более экспрессивным: "подвести слепого под монастырь *срать*" (пардону просим). Тут уж и возразить нечего.

Можно, впрочем, и по-другому рассудить. Слепой идет держась за стену. Сколько он потратит времени -  и куда придет, если стена эта - монастырская?  Но это "вариант для дам".

А вообще посмотрите здесь.
http://otvet.mail.ru/question/17059199